# Upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.1 trashed systemd

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, systemd

Waited like a good boy until 22.04.1 was out, "upgraded" tonight, the installer informed me that there was error installing systemd and my system may be in an unusable state.  It does boot up, in fact for the most part the system runs fine, but updating anything from software updater or command line is a no-go.  I'm hoping not to have to resort to a clean-install; any advice?

sudo apt-get upgrade returns:

```
Setting up systemd (249.11-0ubuntu3.4) ...
systemd-machine-id-setup: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd-sysv:
 systemd-sysv depends on systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4); however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.
 systemd-sysv depends on systemd; however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd-sysv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snapd:
 snapd depends on systemd; however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
 systemd-sysv
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Thanks; appreciate the help; found some googled workarounds re: sym links to the right version but this didn't work for me.  Very disappointing that the ubuntu installer would do this.  I'm in the middle of a fresh install right now, but may take a third option of migrating to pop os or fedora

Comment: Ha ha yeah it's my job to prove to the world that clicking upgrade ruined my ubuntu install?  I'm just a normal user who does basic desktop computing, and ubuntu's upgrade process couldn't even update me to the next long term support release.  And you're trashing me for asking if anyone has a solution?  And thanks for nothing for your stellar response "you can keep digging or fresh install"  wow einstein so helpful lol.

Comment: I have no answer but I do appreciate your story as everyone is being presented the option to upgrade to 22.04.1 and I too am cautious so will wait until I see things are worked out in general.  I'll look for some bugs if any that are known and link them if found.  I understand the frustration, I've been through a few bugs. Device driver conflicts including self created harm to my Ubuntu OS over the years.  Hopefully it will be worked out soon.